# PCA Feature selection using R

Tags: r, feature-selection

I am a biologist. An output of my experiment contains large number of features(which are stored as numbers of columns and 563 rows). The columns are the features which are 8603 in number which are quite high.

So, when I tried to do PCA analysis in R and it gives "out of memory" errors.

I have tried also  doing princomp in pieces, but it does not seem to  work for our
approach.

I tried using the Script given in the link...

http://www.r-bloggers.com/introduction-to-feature-selection-for-bioinformaticians-using-r-correlation-matrix-filters-pca-backward-selection/

But still it does not wok :(

I am trying to use the following code

```
bumpus <- read.table("http://www.ndsu.nodak.edu/ndsu/doetkott/introsas/rawdata/bumpus.html", 
                     skip=20, nrows=49, 
                     col.names=c("id","total","alar","head","humerus","sternum"))

boxplot(bumpus, main="Boxplot of Bumpus' data") ## in this step it is showing the ERROR

# we first standardize the data:
bumpus.scaled <- data.frame( apply(bumpus,2,scale) )
boxplot(bumpus.scaled, main="Boxplot of standardized Bumpus' data")

pca.res <- prcomp(bumpus.scaled, retx=TRUE)
pca.res

# note:
# PC.1 is some kind of average of all the measurements 
#    => measure of size of the bird
# PC.2 has a negative weight for 'sternum' 
#    and positive weights for 'alar', 'head' and 'humerus'
#    => measure of shape of the bird

# first two principal components:
pca.res$x[,1:2]
plot(pca.res$x[,1:2], pch="", main="PC.1 and PC.2 for Bumpus' data (blue=survived, red=died)")
text(pca.res$x[,1:2], labels=c(1:49), col=c(rep("blue",21),rep("red",28)))
abline(v=0, lty=2)
abline(h=0, lty=2)

# compare to segment plot:
windows()
palette(rainbow(12, s = 0.6, v = 0.75)) 
stars(bumpus, labels=c(1:49), nrow=6, key.loc=c(20,-1), 
      main="Segment plot of Bumpus' data", draw.segment=TRUE) 

# compare to biplot:
windows()
biplot(pca.res, scale=0)
# what do the arrows mean?
# consider the arrow for sternum:
abline(0, pca.res$rotation[5,2]/pca.res$rotation[5,1])
# consider the arrow for head:
abline(0, pca.res$rotation[3,2]/pca.res$rotation[3,1])
```

But second line

boxplot(bumpus, main="Boxplot of Bumpus' data") ## shows an error

The error is

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.4 Mb

In addition: There were 27 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Please help!

Comment: Please provide the full code that you are using which is giving the "out of memory" errors.

Comment: And SessionInfo() as well.

Comment: The [`bigmemory`](http://www.bigmemory.org/) or similar packages could be of help (never used them, though, so don't trust me too much on this!...).

Comment: i used bigmemory package but it the matrix is not recognized by PCA funtion :(

Comment: A 563 x 8603 matrix should be a piece of cake for `princomp` without any big memory solutions. I have done it on 996 x 450,000, although with 32 GB RAM and almost a day of time. There must be something wrong with you code, so post it and I'm sure we can solve it.

Comment: I am very suprised that you are able to perform a PCA on a 563x8603 matrix using `princomp`. Actually `princomp` should throw right away the error `'princomp' can only be used with more units than variables`. Try it out: `princomp(matrix( rnorm( 1000 * 10000 ), nrow=1000 ))`. For your case you want to apply the Q-mode PCA implemented in `prcomp`.

Comment: Oh pardon me, I used `prcomp` for my PCA.

Comment: Your problem remains unclear: You are saying the error is thrown after the second line of code (drawing the boxplot) which means it has nothing to do with the PCA. Second, your example shows a 49x6 matrix. Third, you are not showing the warnings which are mentioned in the error. Maybe it's a good advice to start over with a clean R session and try to reproduce your error yourself.

Comment: I'm also confused. When I wrote the answer below your question was related to PCA causing out of memory issues. Now the OP contains a question concerning `boxplot` as well. Please clarify.

Comment: @user1083096 Is there something more we can help you with or is this matter settled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases where the number of features is either huge or exceeds the number of
observations, it is well advised to calculate the principal components based on
the *transposed dataset*. This is especially true in your case because the default
implies calculation of a 8603 x 8603 covariance matrix which itself already
consumes about 500 MB of memory (oh well, this isn't too much, but hey...).

Assuming that the rows of your matrix `X` correspond to observations
and columns correspond to features, center your data and then perform PCA on the
transpose of the centered `X`. There won't be more eigenpairs than number of
observations anyway. Finally, multiply each resulting eigenvector by `X^T`. You do
not need to do the latter for the eigenvalues (see way below for a detailed explanation):

### What you want

This code demonstrates the implementation of PCA on the transposed dataset and compares the results of `prcomp` and the "transposed PCA":

```
pca.reduced <- function(X, center=TRUE, retX=TRUE) {
  # Note that the data must first be centered on the *original* dimensions
  # because the centering of the 'transposed covariance' is meaningless for
  # the dataset. This is also why Sigma must be computed dependent on N
  # instead of simply using cov().
  if (center) {
    mu <- colMeans(X)
    X <- sweep(X, 2, mu, `-`)
  }
  # From now on we're looking at the transpose of X:
  Xt <- t(X)
  aux <- svd(Xt)
  V <- Xt %*% aux$v
  # Normalize the columns of V.
  V <- apply(V, 2, function(x) x / sqrt(sum(x^2)))
  # Done.
  list(X = if (retX) X %*% V else NULL,
       V = V,
       sd = aux$d / sqrt(nrow(X)-1),
       mean = if (center) mu else NULL)
}

# Example data (low-dimensional, but sufficient for this example):
X <- cbind(rnorm(1000), rnorm(1000) * 5, rnorm(1000) * 3)

original   <- prcomp(X, scale=FALSE)
transposed <- pca.reduced(X)

# See what happens:    
> print(original$sdev)
[1] 4.6468136 2.9240382 0.9681769
> print(transposed$sd)
[1] 4.6468136 2.9240382 0.9681769
> 
> print(original$rotation)
               PC1           PC2          PC3
[1,] -0.0055505001  0.0067322416  0.999961934
[2,] -0.9999845292 -0.0004024287 -0.005547916
[3,]  0.0003650635 -0.9999772572  0.006734371
> print(transposed$V)
              [,1]          [,2]         [,3]
[1,]  0.0055505001  0.0067322416 -0.999961934
[2,]  0.9999845292 -0.0004024287  0.005547916
[3,] -0.0003650635 -0.9999772572 -0.006734371
```

### Details

To see why it is possible to work on the transposed matrix consider the
following:

The general form of the eigenvalue equation is

```
          A x = λ x                               (1)
```

Without loss of generality, let `M` be a centered "copy" of your original
dataset `X`. Substitution of `M^T M` for `A` yields

```
          M^T M x = λ x                           (2)
```

Multiplication of this equation by `M` yields

```
          M M^T M x = λ M x                       (3)
```

Consequent substitution of `y = M x` yields

```
          M M^T y = λ y                           (4)
```

One can already see that `y` corresponds to an eigenvector of the "covariance"
matrix of the *transposed* dataset (note that `M M^T` is in fact no real
covariance matrix as the dataset `X` was centered along its columns and not its
rows. Also, scaling must be done by means of the number of samples (rows of `M`)
and not the number of features (columns of `M` resp. rows of `M^T`).

It can also be seen that the eigenvalues are the *same* for `M M^T` and `M^T M`.

Finally, one last multiplication by `M^T` results in

```
          (M^T M) M^T y = λ M^T y                 (5)
```

where `M^T M` is the original covariance matrix.

From equation (5) it follows that `M^T y` is an eigenvector of `M^T M` with
eigenvalue `λ`.